# Search for a substring using pointers-case insensitive

Tags: c++, pointers, search

This is what i have done so far. I am not able to do compare of the substring to the sentence
Please help me in finding the commands to compare a substring to a the sentence

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *arr[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL };


/*
 * block for entering names and storing names dynamically
 */
char sentnc[256]="";
cout << "enter the sentence ";
cin>>sentnc;
arr[0] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen() + 1));

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    char str[256] = "";
    cout << "enter word to be searched ";
    cin >> str;

    names[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
    if (names[i] != NULL)
    {
```

Comment: `arr[0] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen() + 1));` Really? Are you sure???

Comment: by `strlen()` you probably meant: `strlen(sentnc)`?

Comment: Why are you even using `malloc` in C++?

Comment: Do you mean something like [std::strstr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr)?

Comment: yes strlen(sentenc)

Comment: Yes can you help me with that @Galik

Comment: If you are using C++ you really should use `std::string`.  Finding a substring is as easy as `std::string line = ...; std::string word = ...; auto spot = line.find(word);`.  now `spot` is the position found or `std::string::npos`.

Comment: Why sentnc? Is the `e` key broken on your keyboard?